# How To Develop React Node Application For The Shopify Online Store(Not for the merchant page)?

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api-node

This is an odd question. I couldn't find any resource relating to developing a react app and integrating it into the online store(not the merchant page).

https://shopify.dev/apps/getting-started/create, this link only discusses developing an app and integrating it into the Shopify merchant page, not on the online store.

I have gone through the documentation on the above link but could not find anything relevant.

Also, check this link https://shopify.dev/apps/online-store, but creating theme extensions is not what I want as I want to develop a full-fledged application like https://apps.shopify.com/tolstoy

Can you guys point me to the right resource?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Shopify is HTML, CSS and Javascript. There is nothing stopping you from making the merchant end of things ANYTHING you want. Get yourslf a Storefront API token and you're good to go.

As for a lack of resources? HTML, CSS and Javascript are 90% of your journey covered by a bazillion resources including StackOverflow. Shopify documents Storefront API fine too. What more could you ask for?